# C++ How does Allegro or SDL create window?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

How does Allegro or SDL create window for Windows and how to do it by myself?

I'm trying to write WinApi wrapper for games, but I'm completly lost, when I see basic WinApi template and want to wrap it to something like this

```
init();
while()
{
   update();
}
exit();
```

Comment: Nasty gory platform details. You don't want to know. (Hint: They're both open source, why not look it up instead of asking?)

Comment: I've been, but it looks magic to me, especially because it's C not OO C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They use `CreateWindowEx`. A really simple WinAPI app that creates a window looks a little like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
// If you're using MSVC, this is the easiest HINSTANCE. Other compilers
// get it from WinMain and pass in to constructor.
extern "C" IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase;
class Window {
    HWND hWnd;
    static LRESULT __stdcall WindowProc(
        HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        if (Window* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA)))
            return ptr->DoMessage(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        else
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);    
    }
    LRESULT DoMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
         switch(msg) {
         case WM_DESTROY:
             PostQuitMessage(0);
             return 0;
         }
         return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
public:
    bool DoMessages() {
        MSG msg;
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            // Translate the message and dispatch it to WindowProc()
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    Window() {
        WNDCLASSEX wc;
        // clear out the window class for use
        ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
        // fill in the struct with the needed information
        wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
        wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";

        RegisterClassEx(&wc);
        // create the window and use the result as the handle
        hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            L"WindowClass1",    // name of the window class
            L"Wide::Development",   // title of the window
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // window style. Always windowed for now.
            0,    // x-position of the window
            0,    // y-position of the window
            1,    // width of the window
            1,    // height of the window
            NULL,    // we have no parent window, NULL
            NULL,    // we aren't using menus, NULL
            hInstance,    // application handle
            NULL);

        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE); // Snap our window to the user's desktop res, minus taskbar etc.
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(this));
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED); // Make sure that our WindowLongPtr is updated.
    }
};
int main() {
    Window window;
    while(window.DoMessages()) {
        // Do app updates, or sleep() if you're mostly waiting on user input
        Sleep(50);
    }
    // When DoMessages() returns false, the window was destroyed, so return.
}
```

You can look up the MSDN documentation for more information on what these functions do. Essentially, all it does is create a very simple maximized non-fullscreen window, register for input, and when the window is destroyed, quit the application. You'll notice that I actually forwarded the input to the Window object, so this most basic of all frameworks is object-orientated and you can play with inheritance here if you want, just don't forget that the WindowLongPtr functions use a void* and are not type safe.

It's also worth mentioning that on some compilers like MSVC, if you `#include <Windows.h>`, they expect for you to use the WinMain entry point, not main().

The game rendering and update code is typically miles more complex and difficult than the WinAPI, so I'd grab a book on DirectX9.0c or DirectX10.

Comment: "A really simple WinAPI App ..." wow. Thank you, SDL, Allegro, etc.

Comment: @delnan: I don't get it. That thing has to be less than a hundred lines, and if you were to start messing with inheritance, the vast majority of it would be re-usable.

Comment: @delnan
This is charm of windows programming :-)

@DeadMG
Wonderful, it's solving whole my problems! Huge thanks! :-)

Comment: Can be a lot easier. You can get the `HINSTANCE` with `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`. And why store it when you're using it in only one place? First 4 lines gone. Why are you checking `ptr` before calling  `ptr->WindowProc`? It should never be `NULL`. Robustness doesn't count: if it gets random values, it's bloody unlikely to be random `NULL`. The only reason I see is because you call `ShowWindow` before `SetWindowLongPtr`. That's probably a bug. The `WNDCLASSEX wc` initialization can be shorter, with a ` = { sizeof(wc), CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW, ... }` initializer. `Sleep(5)` is just wrong, delete.

Comment: @MSalters: Thanks, but I can see that you don't have a terrible amount of experience. For example, CreateWindowEx sends messages to the WindowProc before it even returns like WM_CREATE, let alone before SetWindowPos updates the LongPtr. If you check the documentation for GetWindowLongPtr, it says that if it hasn't been set yet- say, because CreateWindowEx hasn't returned yet- then the return value is NULL. Why use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`? Using __ImageBase is cleaner, easier, faster. I'm only using it in one place, but you may well need it in more than one if you keep going.

Comment: @MSalters: Sure, I could remove `Sleep(50)`, but then the app would take up huge amounts of CPU waiting for user input looping indefinitely, there's no render code and vsync to keep it reasonable in this example. And I'm sure that you could remove like, 3 lines, using {} initialization for WNDCLASSEX, but, really. Three lines? Great job, you've hugely improved the clarity of my code. I'm pretty sure that it really doesn't matter when ShowWindow is called. The sample works fine, I use it all the time, and all you've managed to do is strip some comments and save like one line of code.

Comment: @DeadMG: You use `DefWindowProc` as the windowproc if you aren't processing messages during CreateWindowEx (and in this design you can't, since `Window::DoMessage` requires `GWLP_USERDATA`). Then you just set `GWLP_WNDPROC` after `GWLP_USERDATA`. The `Sleep` can be deleted when you use GetMessage iso PeekMessage. Sure, it's not a huge number of lines you save, but it's a sizeable percentage.

Comment: It really doesn't matter so much, it's just programmer preference, personally I prefer GetModuleHandle(NULL), but programming is beautyfull, because you can make one thing in many ways so there's no point to telling someone to write  
if()  (new line )
{ (new line )     
}  
instead of if(){}, etc.  
also don't see anything wrong in using sleep, you're just showing other way to get same effect.  
But thanks for tips and your interest :-)